# Calculus of variation problem doesn't have a smooth solution

Tags: calculus-of-variations, optimal-control, euler-lagrange-equation

we define the minimization problem :

$$\min J(x)=\int_{-1}^1x^2(t)[x'(t)-1]dt \quad \text{subject to }x(-1)=0 \quad \text{and} \quad x(1)=0$$

note that $0\leq J(x)$.

and if we consider $x^*(t)=0 \quad \text{for} t\in[-1,0]$ and $x^*(t)=t \quad \text{for} t\in[0,1]$.

it defines a solution de the problem.

But Why this problem doesn't have a solution in $C^1[-1,1]$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem. The $x(t)=0$ is a solution in $\mathcal C^\infty [-1,1]$ of your problem... May be, you want $x(1)=1$ ?

Comment: I changed it ( It was a mistake )